# SignalR Return value to client only works some time

Tags: c#, signalr

I have made a little "life" notification system, so when a user on my website recieves a new mail they get a notification life at the site.

It works but only some times, so i hope that someone can tell me what happens and how i can fix it.

When I debug and check `totalNewMessages` always has a value 0 or above but from what i can see, the problem is between the last line in NotificationHub and the jquery part.

If you look in the jquery Code, i added a `Alert(totalNewMessages);` But it dont always fire. What could be the problem?

NotificationHub.cs

```
IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();


return context.Clients.Client(Users.Values.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProfileId == UserID).ConnectionIds).RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages);
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var hiddenID = $('#HiddenID');
        var Check = $('#Check');
        var notifications = $.connection.notificationHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        notifications.client.recieveNotification = function (totalNewMessages) {
            // Add the message to the page.
            var notification = $('#lblNotificationNumber')
            alert(totalNewMessages);
            if (totalNewMessages > 0) {
                notification.fadeIn('slow');
                notification.text(totalNewMessages);
            }
            else {
                notification.fadeOut('slow');
            }

        };
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            if (hiddenID.val() > 0) {

                notifications.server.check(hiddenID.val());
                notifications.server.sendNotifications(hiddenID.val());


            }
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });

        $('#btnLogout').click(function () {
            $.removeCookie("test");
        });

        //$.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure `Users.Values.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ProfileId == UserID).ConnectionIds` returns proper connection id ?

Comment: Yes I have debugged it and it everytime returns the correct value

Comment: I wish someone would tell that guy with the tutorial that it's "receive", not "recieve"; anyway, to be on-topic: why is that property called "ConnectionIds"? Are you sure this is always just one connection id? Also, are you running multiple instances?